# update nested array of object failed using $set

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection like this

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5446757568567546456"), 
    "name" : "Duck-trailer", 
    "data" : [
        {
            "date" : "1-1-2015", 
            "oldPrice" : 10,
            "price" : 15
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2-1-2015", 
            "oldPrice" : 10
            "price" : 12
        }
      ]
}
```

So I try to select by id and date , then update the price by selecting the date which is nested within the data object.

My query did not work, got error of  `MongoError: cannot use the part..`

```
myModel.update({_id: id, 'data.$.date':'2-1-2015'}, {'$set': {'data.$.price': 100}}, 
    function(err,result) {
})
```

Comment: Try without the $ operator in the query. 'data.date':'2-1-2015'

Answer (score 1):

while matching you dont need the positional operator.

```
db.collection.update({"data.date":"2-1-2015"},{$set:{"data.$.price":100}})
```

this will set the price to 100 where there is a match for the date you entered.

Comment: why `data.date` and then `data.$.price` not `data.price`?